# How to add a trigger in Oracle SQL to update a value after a row was created

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to create triggers for my Oracle database and I always get `compiled with errors` when trying to add it.

The statement is as follows

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_open_amount
AFTER INSERT ON Payment
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Booking SET open_amount = open_amount - NEW.amount WHERE Booking.booking_id = NEW.booking_id;
END;
```

and I get the following error

```
2/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/90      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."BOOKING_ID": invalid identifier
```

The trigger should subtract the amount in the newly created payment row from the open_amount field in the booking row and store the new value.

I managed to get it to work in mysql with the following statement

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_open_amount` AFTER INSERT ON `Payment`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `Booking` SET `open_amount` = `open_amount` - NEW.`amount` WHERE `Booking`.`booking_id` = NEW.`booking_id`;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

but when I try to get it to work in oracle I get stuck.
How can I get the trigger to work because this is all that is still missing for migrating the database from mysql to oracle.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Precede NEW with a colon, i.e. `:new`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check syntax for referring new and old values. It should have preceeding colon (:)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_open_amount
 AFTER INSERT ON Payment
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    UPDATE Booking 
     SET open_amount = open_amount - :NEW.amount 
     WHERE Booking.booking_id = :NEW.booking_id;
   END;
```